# What languages have similar or equivalent array slicing notation to Numpy & why is it not more common?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, slice

Specifically when indexing n>3 dimensional arrays / vectors, why do more languages not adopt the:

```
arr = np.zeros((3, 10, 5, 100)) 
arrSlice = arr[:, 0:5, :, :99]

>   arrSlice.shape
>   (3, 5, 5, 99)
```

style notation for slicing arrays (If I'm not just missing something)...?

Do any other languages have equivalent notation to Numpy, either syntactically or functionally?

Is this something where it's syntactic sugar over Numpy performing more linear looping in C that creates a dichotomy between python / C / cupy that's not available or sensible in other languages? (For e.g., I'm assuming numpy's batch operation notation ends up as sequential looping at a lower level at some point)

Are tensors just not generally very useful / practical data structures outside of machine learning? If so is that more because of most languages not being easily able to execute array operations in parallel using GPUs? Or is it more that people tend not to want to think in multidimensional matrices? Something else?

Are there alternatives in other languages that are equivalent or superior that I'm just not familiar with? It seems like most tend to focus along the first dimension for e.g.:

```
var x = [[0, 1], [2, 5], [3, 4]]

let methodSlice = x.slice(0, 2)
let spreadSlice = &x[0..2];

> [[0, 1], [2, 5]]
```

---

I miss this aspect of python more than anything else in it and it seems like tensors are comparatively less accessible elsewhere.

Thanks ahead of time for any insight you might have, it is a bunch of questions but I couldn't find any equivalent question that had yet been asked.

Comment: You can find that or similar syntax in Matlab, [R](https://www.r-project.org/) or [Julia](https://julialang.org/), and probably others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Is there a downside for less scientific-focused languages not adopting this syntax? I understand why it's so important in the ones that are, but why not just have this in most languages?

Comment: Every syntactic feature of a programming language should be well-motivated and sufficiently demanded to justify its introduction. A badly designed syntax can have far-reaching consequences and affect future features. Python is a dynamic language, very flexibly designed and oriented to developer experience. Strongly-typed or lower-level languages might have more trouble defining how a syntax like this should exactly work in every case (think of types, memory views vs copies, etc), for a limited gain. In most cases, slightly more verbose APIs within existing syntax are a safer bet.

Comment: For example, [here](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html#slicing-and-indexing) is an example of how a C++ library emulates NumPy in a conveniently enough manner. See [Array slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) for more examples from other languages.

Comment: Is it safe to say then that more business-oriented languages probably don't warrant the need  to justify the benefits this  style of syntax provides over the potential downsides being less explicit might bring?

Comment: I personally would avoid using "business-oriented" as a classification for programming languages, unless that term has been given a determined meaning in advance... C++, Java, Python, JS, Scala, Go, Rust, even Julia, all are very much used in different ways by businesses, so it may be misleading depending on the case. But I'd certainly say that some languages are more popular for scientific applications and thus (or precisely because) it makes more sense for them to have specialised syntax. Note however that Python wasn't so big in science before NumPy/SciPy, so sometimes things change, too.

Comment: A good example of this, btw, can be found in [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), where Python introduced the matrix multiplication operator (`@`). It is an odd addition the the language syntax because it was added with no uses by the standard library, that is, specifically for third-party libraries to override, in principle, to implement matrix multiplication (although one could implement whatever operation for that operator with `__matmul__`). There is a discussion in the document about why it makes sense for them to add that as a language syntax feature.

Answer (score 4):

R's slicing notation is similar: https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/slicing-dataframes.html